# Count and compare files in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, wc

I want to just compare the number of lines in two files. Below is the list of names of files. One file contains names/location of fastq files; the other file contains names/location of bam files.

File1 (consists of fastq files)

```
/tmp/564105.1.standard.q/FASTQ/Sample_ATLL2456T1_spleen_R1.fastq.gz
/tmp/564105.1.standard.q/FASTQ/Sample_ATLL2456T1_tumor_R1.fastq.gz
/tmp/564105.1.standard.q/FASTQ/Sample_TALL3139T1_1023_R1.fastq.gz
```

File2 (consists of bam files)

```
/tmp/564105.1.standard.q/starfusion_dest/Sample_ATLL2456T1_tumor_R1.fastq./Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/tmp/564105.1.standard.q/starfusion_dest/Sample_TALL3139T1_1023_R1.fastq./Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/tmp/564105.1.standard.q/starfusion_dest/Sample_ATLL2456T1_spleen_R1.fastq./Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

Code:

```
if [ "wc -l $File1" == "wc -l $File2" ] ; then
  echo "Bam files from File2 do exist for each sample"
else
  echo "Bam files do not exist for every sample"
fi
```

There is some error in my code, as I always get the statement from else that is "Bam files do not exist" whereas the count remains same in both File1 and File2.

Comment: Save the no. of lines in variables and compare them e.g. `fastq=$(wc -l <file1); bam=$(wc -l <file2); if [ $fastq -eq $bam ]...` or without vars `if [ $(wc -l <file1) -eq $(wc -l <file2) ]...`

Comment: Or even use command substitution at the condition line  `if [ $(wc -l < /path/to/the/file1) -eq $(wc -l /path/to/the/file2) ] then ...`

Comment: is comparing line counts adequate?  is it possible for there to be duplicate entries in either file?  or just equal numbers of files, without any actual connection between some of the files in File1 and/or some in File2?